# when i click back section 1 header the section 1 content is not closing

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I have a react code working fine when i click section 1 header the section 1 content is opening.
- but the problem is when i click back section 1 header the section 1 content is not closing.
- similarly it should happen for other sections.
- can you guys tell what is the problem.
- providing my code below

```or-tag-here
enhanceSection: function(child) {
        var selectedId = this.state.selected,
```

Comment: This is directly copied from [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/4/) that's easily found by google search (as well as fiddles that do what you're looking for.) What have you tried? Here is the [accordion documentation](https://github.com/glennflanagan/react-collapsible).

Comment: @wahwahwah hello i need to add the .down-arrow class to the div when the accordion opens up. http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/26/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to close the section if you click on it while it's already open?

If so, I added this if statement to your onSelect-function:

```
onSelect: function(id) {
    if (this.state.selected === id) {
    this.setState({selected: ""});
  } else {
    this.setState({selected: id});
  } 
}
```

Comment: but when we click on the content its not clicking...I updated your code here http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/12/

Comment: @texirv I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you're looking for.

Comment: I mean this part    Section 1 content

Comment: hello i need to add the .down-arrow class to the div when the accordion opens up. http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/26/